# how to display post variables in email body by PHPmailer

Tags: post, phpmailer

Can any one help me to integrate a form with PHPMailer. I have following form.

```html
<form method="POST">
 <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" size="30"></p>
<p>Email Address:<input type="text" name="email" size="30"></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I just need to display POST variables in my receiving email's body. I have search and refer alot and spend hours in it, everyone clarifies it with high level explanation. As i am not a programmer can anyone explain me how can i do this with simple explanation. I just done a method as follows but it did'nt work.

```html
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$mail->Body = "
    <html>
    <h2><b>".$name." ".$email."</b></h2>
    </html>";
```

When i tried the above method i am getting error in this line '$name = $_POST['name'];'. The error message is:  Notice: Undefined index:' I think i am wrong with my placing order of codes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php
if(array_key_exists("name",$_POST) && $_POST["name"] != "" && array_key_exists("email",$_POST) && $_POST["email"] != ""){
    require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Manager');
    $mail->addAddress('mail@gmail.com', 'Administrator');     // Add a recipient


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $mail->Body = "<h2><b>".$name." ".$email."</b></h2>";
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
} else {

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" size="30" required></p>
            <p>Email Address:<input type="email" name="email" size="30" required></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....let me now which section i need to wrap with your code

Comment: Edited the answer to add clarify which lines I talked about.

Comment: Now i am getting this error: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Message body empty

Comment: That means that you don't have any data sent via post. Could you add more of your php and the filenames where the code is saved to the question?

Comment: I edited your code a bit to only send the mail if some data was submitted via post. Using a form you can not use the data from the form within the very same instance of the page because it is send to another new instance. This new instance will then take care of your submitted data and send the mail. Setting the input fields to required will prevent the user from submitting an empty form and setting the type of the  second field to email will force a validation.

Comment: thanks jonathan, its working. one more question, if i add more variables in future, should i need to add those in the ''array_key_exists'.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it worked like you wanted it to Work? You have to check if the form was submitted and an easy way to do so is to check if a value for any required field is transmitted. No, you won't have to add more gut you have to make sure that the field you are asking for is transmitted with every submission. It is possible to have an additional Input type hidden with a name like transmition and a value of one. The user can't change a hidden field so it will be transmitted every time.